# Use swing in a different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm developing a cli-based custom web crawler in Java. Since it needs to have a user-friendly graphical interface for showing the result, I should add a swing frame to that involving some trees, labels, tables and so on.
That graphical interface is one of its switches, and must be started just in case user calls it. Thus, I have to start this interface in a new thread so that the application can proceed with other tasks and update components inside of GUI frame if needs. 
My GUI class is some thing like:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
   ......
   public static JLabel urlLabel;
   ......
   public static void run() {
      urlLabel = new JLabel();
      urlLabel.setText("Test Url");
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              new Frame().setVisible(true);
          }
      });
   }
   .....
 }
```

And, I fork it from my main class like this:

```
.....
if(cmd.gui){
   Frame.run();
   Frame.urlLabel.setText("New Url");
 }
......
```

Unfortunately, the text of label doesn't change. I already tested `repaint()`, `revalidate()` and such other functions like these, but, nothing turned up.
I tested `getText()` in order to make sure it is possible to access `urlLabel` from main class, and it worked (I could retrieved text of label).

I was wondering how I can sort out this issue? (Basically, I need to start a swing frame in a different thread and control its components from the main thread)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just need to use the dedicated swing thread to change the UI elements, like you already did with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, every time! Or maybe I understand your problem wrong?

Comment: @xander I already did it. The swing starts in a new dedicated thread, and I need to update/change its components. As I explained that is a custom web crawler, and I need to add new collected data to the GUI whilst the application is crawling the website.

Comment: @SinaYazdanmehr Also remember, Swing is NOT thread safe and all updates to the UI MUST be made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  You should also not rely on `static` as a cross object communication method, it's just a pain in the code. Instead, you should share a model between the UI and the other parts of the code. The UI can use an observer pattern to obtain updates when the model changes and ensure that it's update from within the EDT through `invokeLater`. Typically you would use `SwingWorker` which would drive the "non-UI" part, but through which could notify  UI

Comment: @MadProgrammer I checked `SwingWorker` as well, but it didn't work. (Maybe I used that in a wrong way, will double check it)

Comment: I think you misunderstood @xander's comment.  You need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to update the text.  `invokeLater` will post an event that will be picked up by the Swing event thread.  This thread will then run the text update.  Updating the text from any other thread will not give you the desired results.

Comment: yes you need to run every UI setter code inside the swing dispatch thread. e.g. like this: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> Frame.urlLabel.setText("New Url"));` (that's a java lambda in case you haven't seen that before).

Comment: @xander Yes you are right. I misunderstood. Thank you very much for helping

Answer (score 0):

If you use `invokeLater()`, your Runnable will be started in the EventThread after the current operation in this thread is finished. If your label is not updated, it might be that your EventThread is busy doing something else - e.g. crawling the web.

You definitely need to make sure that your crawling work is done in another thread (start a new one, don't use the one that runs anyway, since this is most probably the EventThread). Then you might use `invokeLater()` in this other Thread to change the label in the EventThread.

Hint: You can check if you are in the EventThread by using `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()`.

Remember that your data/models will be used by different threads and that this might cause problems when the data is changed in your worker thread while your GUI is trying to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping.
Finally, I could overcome this obstacle by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` for updating the label's text.
I mention the approach here, since someone else might need it:

The main class:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
......
  private static JLabel urlLabel;
......
  public JLabel getU(){
    return urlLabel;
  }
  public static void run() {
  urlLabel = new JLabel();
  urlLabel.setText("Test Url");
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          new Frame().setVisible(true);
      }
  });
 }
  .....
}
```

The GUI class:

```
if(cmd.gui){
     Frame().run();
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
                 gui.getU().setText("New Url");
          }
     });
}
.....
```

Just a question about this manner:
Since I need to update some labels and tree nodes a couple of times during crawling, wanted to know if starting a new `Runnable` for each of those would be overload? If yes, how can I manage that?

**---UPDATE---**

According to the @xander's comment, it is possible to use lambda instead of `Runnable`. I think lambda doesn't have overload as much as a new object does.

Comment: 1. Lambdas are just embedded methods, so i'ts essentially the same as your code, just less to write/read . 2. if you can combine your UI changed to one `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` call, but you can run it many times if needed, it just syncs your `Runnable` in the swing UI thread.